# each IntelliJ module to a different Git repository

Tags: android, eclipse, git, android-studio

I am just migrating my Android development from Eclipse+SVN to Android Studio+Git.

In Eclipse I had 2 projects: a library project and a app project using the library. Both were kept in separate SVN repos.

Now, I have imported my Eclipse App project, and it has automatically created a single IntelliJ project with 2 modules: the 'app' and the 'library'. I have pushed that to my Git repo and things work.

The last thing that I want to do is split the Android Studio project into 2 separate Git repos, just like it was before. Here I am having a hard time figuring out which filoes belong to which repo. Here's my project structure:

```
.gitignore
.idea/ 
build.gradle
project.iml
app/  
gradle/ 
gradlew
gradlew.bat
library/
settings.gradle
```

(plus some other files like local.settings that are not tracked).

Now, the library/ directory clearly belongs to the 'library' Git repo; likewise the 'app/' directory belongs to the 'app' Git repo. But what about, say, 'settings.gradle'? The contents of this file is:

```
include ':library'
include ':app'
```

so it clearly depends on both modules. Likewise there are quite a few files in .idea that contain references to both modules.

Things were much simpler in Eclipse, where each Project was completely in its own directory so it was clear what belongs to which Repo.

Comment: Did you take a look to git submodules? I think it will be the easiest solution for you. Just wonder why do you want to have two repos

Comment: another way you can create separate library project for library module and include it into your app.

Comment: Hmm, I wouldn't like to create 2 separate IntelliJ project as then I'd have to juggle the Android Studio Windows when I am developing, modify the library, recompile, re-include the library in my app, etc - seems cumbersome.

Git submodules: I'll take a look at that. The reason why I want to keep the library separate is because it is the library that's the point of development here; my users will be other android developers who will use this library in their projects. The 'app' module is only a collection of Activities, each one showing a single feature of the library for educational purposes.

Comment: Indeed git submodules solve the problem. Thanks Eugen!